# Parsing array with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm loosing a little with lodash. I have an array like this :

```
["01017-00-0000",
"01025-00-0000",
"10000-01-1112",
"10000-01-1223",
"10000-01-1224",
"10000-01-1551",
"10000-01-1552",
"10000-02-2702",]
```

and I want to get something like that :

```
. 01017
   . all users
. 01025
   . all users
. 10000
   . Sections : 01, 02
   . Users : 01-1112, 01-1223, 01-1224, 01-1551, 01-1552, 02-2702
```

I trying to do in online tester but , i'm going crazy !
Please help me !

Thank you every one  !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted.

Comment: What sort of data structure do you want ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example for starting

```
var existant = ["01017-00-0000",
"01025-00-0000",
"10000-01-1112",
"10000-01-1223",
"10000-01-1224",
"10000-01-1551",
"10000-01-1552",
"10000-02-2702",];

result=[];
_.filter(existant ,function(o) { 
    var p = o.substr(0,5);
  var t = o.substr(6,2);
    bloc=[];
  blocll=[];
    bloc.push(p);
  if (t == '00') { blocll.push('All users');  }
  else
  { _.filter(existant, function(oo){
    var pp = oo.substr(0,5);
    var tt = oo.substr(6,2);
    var ll = oo.substr(9,4);
    if(pp == p && tt == t) { blocll.push(ll); }
  }) ;      
  }
  bloc.push(blocll);
  result.push(bloc);
});
console.log(result);
```